# Copy \ paste to input type = file not working in IE or Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, clipboard

I'm trying to create a function in jQuery / JS to upload images from the clipboard to a input upload field. The code works flawless in Chrome and Firefox, but i cant get it to work in Internet explorer 11 or Edge. On Edge the code shows the toast message with "Success", but doesn't fill the files object of the input field. On IE it doesn't do anything at all.

CodePen: https://codepen.io/Kermit713/pen/zYGorez?editors=1111

Below my code:

```
$(function(){

    $("body").bind('paste', function(je){

        var e = je.originalEvent;

        var  inputFieldsIds = [
            'exampleInputId_1',
            'exampleInputId_2',
        ];

        if($('html').find('input[type=file]').length > 0){

            $('html').find('input[type=file]').each(function(){
                var inputField = $(this);

                if(jQuery.inArray(inputField.attr('id'), inputFieldsIds) !== -1){
                    clipboardToUpload(inputField,e);
                }
            });

        }

        function clipboardToUpload(inputField,e) {

            var fileInput = inputField[0];
            var clipboard = e.clipboardData.files;
            var hasImg = false;

            for (var i = 0; i < e.clipboardData.items.length; i++) {
                var item = e.clipboardData.items[i];

                if (item.type.indexOf('image') != -1) {

                    fileInput.focus();
                    fileInput.files = clipboard;
                    toastr.success('Succes');
                    hasImg = true;

                }
            }

            if(!hasImg){
                toastr.warning('No img')
            }
        }

    });
});
```

Does anyone know the solution to paste a image from the clipboard to the input type=file on Edge and IE?

Comment: I tested the issue with iE and MS Edge browser and I am able to reproduce the issue. At present, you can try to use the MS Edge Chromium browser as a workaround. Your code is working fine with it. I will try to provide feedback to Microsoft about this issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I cant use the workarround since the clients using the website mostly are stuck on the IE 11 browser. I look forward to the feedback from Microsoft. Thank you in advance.

Comment: For security reasons IE has long blocked certain activities on file upload controls to ensure info about the end users file system is not revealed. I would not expect this to change. They might enable pasting the file in Edge Chromium... but likely not the URL (or the full URL would be hidden (or faked) when accessing from JavaScript.

Comment: I agree with the suggestion given by @scunliffe. So if you have to support this feature in your site then moving to the MS Edge Chromium can fix this issue. MS Edge Chromium also has inbuilt IE mode. I suggest you make a test with it.